# Where can I find the three word walls for the Phantom Form shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Wyrmstooth adds some cut content back into the game including the Phantom Form shout the Greybeards use when teaching the Dragonborn Unrelenting Force. Where can I find all three words of this shout?

Answer (score 2):

`Fiik`: This one can be found in Wyrmstooth Barrow, in the lower levels. I don't remember the exact location, but its behind the draugr fighting the bandits.

`Loh`: This word is inside of Haetar's Cave, shortly before you are about to leave the cave.

`Sah`: Fort Valus, inside the Tomb of Volum, which is a secret passage in the northeast (unsure!) of the castle.